# Word or expression for imagining a sound?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I ask you to think of a place you love, you might mentally "see" that place in your mind.  We usually call this "visualisation".

I would like to know if there is a similar word for when you think of a sound and you mentally "hear" it in your mind.  Is there such a word or expression?

For example: I love the sound of the wind blowing thru the aspen forest.  When I miss my home in the mountains, I just visualise those beautiful aspens and I  _________ the sound of the wind.

Comment: Read The New Yorker, Jan 9, 2017.  Pages 70-73.  There is probably a suitable word in there somewhere.

Comment: I think you would probably have to make do with something like "...and it *evokes in me* the sound of the wind".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***Audiation***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_music_learning_theory) - the sensation of hearing or feeling sound when it is not physically present.

So, when I am missing my home in the mountains (!) I just ***audiate*** the sound of the wind and I am there (in my mind's ear).

Comment: +1 for a great word! You must do this a lot.

Comment: @Cascabel - curious thing, when I'm learning a piece I have to be careful to listen to how I'm actually playing (as opposed to how I imagine I'm playing!)

Comment: Can you give the noun form of that word. IE: visualise : visualisation :: audiate : _______?

Comment: @RiceFlourCookies - Audiate : Audiation.